# Invalid head for new Pull Request on GitKraken

Tags: github, pull-request, gitkraken

I'm having trouble creating a pull-request on github using GitKraken.

When I drop a branch on an other one and select *"Start a pull-request to XX from YY"*, I'm correctly prompted with the contextual window *"Create a pull request"*.

But when I submit it, I have the following error:

```
Failed to create pull request
{
    "message": "Validation failed",
    "errors": [{
        "resource": "PullRequest",
        "field": "head",
        "code": "Invalid"
    }],
    "documentation_url": "https://developer.github.com/v3/pulls/#create-a-pull-request"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a very unhelpful response from the GitHub API. I did some digging and was able to find some issues:

- [Issue 1](https://github.com/github/VisualStudio/issues/453)
- [Issue 2](https://github.com/github/hub/issues/523)

I'm afraid there is a wide variety of reason to get such a response. I suggest you try to do a pull request ([documentation](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-a-pull-request/)) directly on Github's page to find out whether the error is coming from your code itself (*like merging the branches is not possible* ) or the API request the GitKraken is making.

Comment: I do realize it's a hard to reproduce problem :/ I managed to successfully create the PR directly on Github with the same branches. Thanks a lot for digging !

Comment: After further tries, my repo seems to be the problem as I can create PR from GitKraken on other repos ... Will continue searching

Answer (score 1):

Found out that the problem came from the settings of the remote repo.
The repo has been transferred from organization A to B. For some reasons, pushing and pulling is still working on A (thanks to the redirection), but the PR creation doesn't.

I set the correct remote and it works now.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same issue. Turns out the KEY to this entire API call is that it will only raise PR IF such branch already exists on the remote.

Say you are currently in `feature/branchA` and you want to push this via API to create PR.

Well you basically need to ensure that branch `feature/branchA` is already in remote.
In other words, you simply would've done `git push origin feature/branchA` BEFORE using this GITHUB API. Then all that the API does is make a PR for you rather than going to the GUI and doing it yourself. Bit confusing but yeah.